# How read json file, and convert it to POJO using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I need to pass values from a json file to a java class,the json file is like this exemple:

```
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Gold",
        "description":"Shiny!",
        "spriteId":1,
        "consumable":true,
        "effectsId":[1]
    },
```

i need to map,i did this:

```
Items i = new Items();


Map<String, Items> mapaNomes = new HashMap<String, Items>();
mapaNomes.put("Gold",i);
mapaNomes.put("Apple",i );
mapaNomes.put("Clain Mail",i );
```

I'm new to android Development and I'm probably forgetting something because the following is not working,someone can help in find what`s is wrong?

```
BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Items Items = gson.fromJson((BufferedReader) mapaNomes, Items.class);
```

Comment: Why are you casting a `Map` to a `BufferedReader` which has nothing to do with the json?

Comment: `DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);` first convert your json reponse to DataObject and then map it. here `br` is `BufferedReader ` object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Create your POJO representation for your Json.

```
public class MapaNomes() {
    String name;
    String description;
    // etc

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // create your other getters and setters
}
```

I find this tool is handy for transforming json to POJO. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

### 2. Read your file.json. Turn it into object

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("file.json"));
MapaNomes mapaNomes = new Gson().fromJson(reader, MapaNomes.class);
```

### Bonus

I'm thinking that there might be numerous json objects in your file.json such as:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Gold",
    "description":"Shiny!",
    "spriteId":1,
    "consumable":true,
    "effectsId":[1]
},
...
{
    "id":999,
    "name":"Silver",
    "description":"Whatever!",
    "spriteId":808,
    "consumable":true,
    "effectsId":[2]
},
```

If this is the case, then you can do the following:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("file.json"));
List<MapaNomes> mapaNomeses = new Gson().fromJson(
                                reader, 
                                new TypeToken<List<Review>>() {}.getType());

Then you can do whatever you want with each and every one of them

for (MapaNomes mapaNomes : mapaNomeses) {
    // whatever
}
```